# Проблема связанная с удалением ruby 1.9.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gems, bundler

Удалил директорию с ruby-1.9.1 через `sudo rm` (понимаю, что достаточно глупый поступок).
Установил ruby-2.2.1, и теперь при обновлении гемов или запуске bundler'a получаю:

```
madbunny@borschgames:/var/data/redmine$ sudo bundle install

<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError) from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

rubygems.rb удалился вместе с ruby. Видел подобные вопросы - не помогло...

Comment: Попробуй использовать rvm.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Установи [RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install):**

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

**2) Перезагрузи RVM:**

```
rvm reload
```

**3) Установи нужную версию:**

```
rvm install ruby-2.2.1
```

**4) Чтобы использовать нужную версию можно либо:**

а) В корне своего проекта для автоматического переключения на нужную версию создать файл `.rvmrc` с содержимым:

```
rvm use ruby-2.2.1
```

И вновь зайдя в папку проекта получишь авто переключение на эту версию.

б) Либо можно в консоле вручную на нужную версию переключаться:

```
rvm use ruby-2.2.1
```

**5) Наконец то выполни:**

```
bundle
```

**PS:** Вот неплохая [статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/120504/) о RVM на русском.